# Change location header in redirect responses from HTTP to HTTPS in Kong API Gateway

Tags: redirect, api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

I have the following setup

User Request --> AWS ELB Application load balancer --> Kong Gateway --> Integration

The SSL termination happens at application load balancer.

One of my endpoint makes the Integration respond a redirect URL with a code 302. Ex. when I make a request to https://api.domain.my/a/b/c should make the integration return a redirect path /x/y/z

This redirect request with a status of 302 reaches the API gateway which should add a location header to the response with the complete URL i.e. https://api.domain.my/x/y/z

But the response I get in the header on my browser is http://api.domain.my/x/y/z in the location header. I am guessing this is happening because my SSL termination happens at the ELB and hence Kong is just returning http:// in the location header.

Is there a workaround for this? How can I use the response transformer maybe to achieve this?

Is there any better way to achieve this?